# Variable $connection is undefined. Impossible, what is happening there?

Tags: php

***Objective:*** I am in the process of creating a php login script.

***Problem:*** I can't seem to be able to make my includes recognize the $connection variable even though it should be clearly defined in connection.php. As a result the value of my variable is nothing / NULL.

***What I tried:*** I started with mysql but quickly noticed that it was the wrong approach and converted my code to mysqli. I checked for typos in all the $connection variables I have. I made sure the paths are correct. As a last resort I did a Google search but didn't find an answer or any useful hint to my scenario.

***Problem:*** What is the reason for my variable not being defined?

***Error Messages:***

**All those messages are related to this single variable no being defined for some reason:**

*Php Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\aspie\Php\Core\Common.php on line 4*

*Php  Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\aspie\Php\Core\Common.php on line 4*

*Php  Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\aspie\Php\Core\Functions\Members.php on line 4*

*Php Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\aspie\Php\Core\Functions\Members.php on line 4*

*Php Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\aspie\Php\Core\Functions\Members.php on line 5*

**// INITIALIZER**

```
<?php
session_start();
// error_reporting(NULL);

include 'Connection.php';
include 'Common.php';
include 'Functions/Members.php';

?>
```

**// ERROR MESSAGES **

```
<?php
$connection_error = 'Our website is experiencing technical issues, please come back later.';
$wrong_login = 'Password and name are wrong.';
$member_registered = 'Access has been denied. You do not seem to be a registered user.';
?>
```

**// CONNECTION **

```
<?php
include 'Errors.php';

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'project') or exit ($connection_error);
?>
```

**// COMMON **

```
<?php
error_reporting();
function sanitize($connection, $data) {
    global $connection;
    global $data;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data);
}
?>
```

**// MEMBERS **

```
<?php
function member_registered($connection, $name) {
    $name = sanitize($connection, $name);
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `members` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
    return (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) ? true : false;
}

?>
```

**// LOGIN **

```
<?php
include 'Php/Core/Initializer.php';

    if (member_registered($connection, 'ee')) {
        echo "exists";
    }
    die("eee");
    echo error_reporting();
if (empty($_POST) == false) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['name'];

    if (empty($name) OR empty($password)) {
        echo $wrong_login;
    }

    else if (member_registered($connection, $name) == false) {
        echo $member_registered;
    }
}
?>
```

UPDATE:

Now what I get: existseee;

The conditional doesnt work now even though its all set up right. Username doesnt exist so it should'nt echo "exists:

```
if (member_registered($connection, 'ee')) {
    echo "exists";
}
die("eee");
```

Comment: Variable is defined, but it's not seen in a function's scope

Comment: `$connection` is not available in the functions scope. Pass it as a parameter `function member_registered($connection,$name) {` and then add the connection to the call `if (member_registered($connection,'ee')) {`

Comment: All variables in a function are in a different scope. You need to either pass the variable as parameter or set it in the function as global `function ...() { global $connection; [...more code]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the `$connection` variable inside your sanitize function isn't reachable.

Try to pass the `$connection` variable into your function, like this:

```
function sanitize($data, $connection) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data);
}
```

Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

**UPDATE**

In **// MEMBERS ** you need to include the new parameter as well:

```
function member_registered($name, $connection) {
    $name = sanitize($name, $connection);
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `members` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
    return (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

and because of that your **// LOGIN ** should be updated as well:

```
include 'Php/Core/Initializer.php';

    if (member_registered('ee', $connection)) {
        echo "exists";
    }
    die("eee");
    echo error_reporting();
if (empty($_POST) == false) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['name'];

    if (empty($name) OR empty($password)) {
        echo $wrong_login;
    }

    else if (member_registered($name, $connection) == false) {
        echo $member_registered;
    }
}
```

And make sure that the `$connection` variable is reachable everywhere where you need it.

**UPDATE #2**

Answer to your update:

it should be like this:

```
if (member_registered('ee', $connection)) {
    echo "exists";
}
```

and not like this:

```
if (member_registered($connection, 'ee')) {
    echo "exists";
}
```

the `$connection` is the second parameter.

Comment: I just updated my code but still firing errors. You can see my update as I edited my question

Comment: I updated my code with your fix. Issue is that my conditional doesnt work now which checks if the user exists. You can read it under "Update" in my edited question. Its all set up right though.

Comment: Please check my UPDATE #2

Comment: I changed that since  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Comment: This should not effect the parameters of the `mysqli_query()` method. If you want to change the order of parameters for the `member_registered` method, then you need to change it everywhere where `member_registered()` is used.

Comment: in a matter of fact I did: Connection, param2. Everywhere where it was needed. For some reason my die and my if fires

Comment: No error, well actually both if and die echo out: existsDoesnt exist on the screen. Replaced ee with Doesnt exist. So if the user exists then echo exists and if it doesnt then does not exist. Both are shown for some reason